# Increase PWM bit resolution on only one timer 2 output

Tags: pwm

I am new here and I know that this basic question has been answered in the past but what I want to know is this. And I cant figure out how to add this to one of those threads. Sorry in advance if I am posting this wrong.

Arduino Uno

I have a motor driven PWM off output 10 and output 9 is used for the display, can I change the resolution of output 10 only to 16 bit? or will both outputs need to be used as PWM when changing timer 2 to 16 bit? All of the coding samples I see are for changing both outputs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with PWM libraries within the Arduino framework, but I've taken a look at the [microcontroller datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf), and it appears there is a way to operate 16-bit PWM on pin 9 (OC1A) while retaining normal port operation on pin 10 (OC1B). Please refer to table 20-4 on page 170 of the datasheet if you are willing to configure the timer manually. It is rather involving unfortunately. Perhaps there is a library for that.

Comment: I think I agree with you, after reading the datasheet, therefore I will just rewire the board and not use output pin 9. If I get a little time I will do some testing with variations but for now I don't have the time. Thank you for the info!

Comment: @user49780, read the updated answer from Gerben

Comment: You mean “Timer 1”. Both outputs 9 and 10 are driven from Timer 1, not Timer 2.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I did mean timer 1.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't use PWM (i.e. analogWrite) on pin 9, any changes made to timer1 won't affect pin 9.

<strike>It will change both outputs, as both use the same (single) timer.</strike>

But you can use code to convert a 8-bit PWM value to a 16-bit value by simply multiplying the 8-bit value by 256.

Comment: The title is misleading. I don't think that the question was if you can have different PWM resolution on 9 and 10. I understand  the question so that one of the pins 9 and 10 should be PWM and second a simple digital pin. (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: @Juraj I think you might be right there.

Comment: Some of the stuff I had read about changing the timer 1 to 16 bit mode made it sound like both pin 9 and 10 could only be used for PWM then. Of course this seemed incorrect but I could not find anything with a clear answer. I have since rewired the project to not use pin 9 in case it was true. I will sometime soon figure this out with some testing. Currently have little time for that. I do have a new issue that I am trying to figure out. It has to do with the scaling. It is not working as expected. But I will look more into it before starting a new thread if I can't figure that one out.

Comment: The `COM1A1` and `COM1A0` bits in the `TCCR1A` enable PWM on pin 9. As long as you leave them at `0`, pin 9 will act like a normal GPIO pin.